# how to make post request with row http body using swift as postman request test?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

let httpbody = object.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
request.httpBody = httpbody
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly generate a code from postman itself. Also, for your reference, you can call post request with row body as given below.

```
let headers = [
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
    ]

    let parameters = ["order": ["line_items": [
                                            ["variant_id": 18055889387589,
                                             "quantity": 1]
                     ]]] as [String : Any]

    let postData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])

    if let data = postData {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://")! as URL,
                                          cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                          timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        request.httpBody = data as Data

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
            } else {
                let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
                print(httpResponse?.statusCode ?? 0)


                let reponseData = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                print("responseData: \(reponseData ?? "Blank Data")")
            }
        })

        dataTask.resume()
    }
```

Let me know if you have any query.

Thanks.

Comment: thank you ... i got 200 status code response but the problem still there ... cannot find the order on server as it solved within postman test while using row in http body in post request ... i cannot read data also in dataTask...

Comment: Can you please post your postman response and swift API call response in your question. So that we can have more idea.

Comment: here is the response https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/orders/order#create ... you will find a title scroll down the page at title : Create a simple order with only a product variant ID

Comment: I update my code. Can you please replace it and check again and let me know what you got in the console.

Comment: if you can send me your email may i can forward the api to you ! im not sure how i can send it to you in here !!

Comment: check your inbox by slashgamers@gmail

Comment: checked but can you please come online in chat. I am getting an error in postman with a demo request.

Comment: Ok how can i ? Sorry im new!

Comment: from your gmail accout you can chat with users. I send you a chat message in gmail.

Comment: can you please send me one variant_id to place an order.

Comment: Above code is working fine with your given variant_id.