# Swift - Send NSDictionary as parameter in POST

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlconnection

I am able to make a successful POST request in POSTMAN like this:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "myDictKey": {
    "key0": "blah",
    "key1": "blah",
    "key2": "blah"
  } 
}
```

However, when I try to make this POST request in swift, the POST is unsuccessful. The NSDictionary param doesn't seem to get encoded as expected.

**Swift Code**

```
    let dictParam = ["key0": "blah", "key1": "blah", "key2": "blah"] as NSDictionary
    let urlString = MY_URL
    let url = URL(string: urlString)!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let parameters: [String: Any] = [
        "id": "1",
        "myDictKey": dictParam
    ]

    request.httpBody = parameters.percentEncoded()

     let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            completion(nil, error?.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        do {
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [.allowFragments]) as? NSDictionary {
                if response?.statusCode() == 200 {
                    if let jsonResponse = json.value(forKeyPath: "response") as? NSDictionary {
                            completion(jsonResponse, nil)
                            return

                } else if response?.statusCode() == 401 {
                    completion(nil, "Unauthorized")
                } else {
                    completion(nil, "Something went wrong. Try again later")
                }
            }
        } catch {
            completion(nil, "Something went wrong. Try again later")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

**percentEncoded()**

```
// MARK: - Dictionary
extension Dictionary {
  func percentEncoded() -> Data? {
    return map { key, value in
        let escapedKey = "\(key)".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed) ?? ""
        let escapedValue = "\(value)".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed) ?? ""
        return escapedKey + "=" + escapedValue
    }
    .joined(separator: "&")
    .data(using: .utf8)
 }
}
```

**CharacterSet**

```
// MARK: - CharacterSet
extension CharacterSet {
    static let urlQueryValueAllowed: CharacterSet = {
    let generalDelimitersToEncode = ":#[]@" // does not include "?" or "/" due to RFC 3986 - Section 3.4
    let subDelimitersToEncode = "!$&'()*+,;="

    var allowed = CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed
    allowed.remove(charactersIn: "\(generalDelimitersToEncode)\(subDelimitersToEncode)")
    return allowed
  }()
}
```

Comment: `parameters.percentEncoded()` That's the big unknown of your code. What's the code behind percentEncoded?

Comment: @Larme Added it into the question

Comment: @Larme Also added the allowed CharacterSet

Comment: I think you should use JSON for the body, but still. Did you know that POSTMAN can generate Swift Code for its request? Do it, and compare what's the diff (even if it's bad written code, logic should be there), you'll see.

Comment: @larme `Did you know that POSTMAN can generate Swift Code for its request`. Thanks for that tip. That lead me to this question which solved my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53349979/how-to-make-post-request-with-row-http-body-using-swift-as-postman-request-test

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to JSONSerialize the parameter:

```
request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)
```

Comment: I replaced `request.httpBody = parameters.percentEncoded()` with `request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)` - still same error

Comment: My server's response code is 200, but nothing is actually getting posted

Comment: Is your actual requirement to post data as json or not?

Comment: I don't think so, in postman I am posting as RAW, but in swift i do see that i have x-www-form-encoded, maybe that has something to do with the issue

Comment: Then what is your objective here? Post the entire scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can create **[Encodable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/encodable)** model for your request body.

Something like this:

```
struct MyRequestBodyModel: Encodable {
    let id: String
    let myDictKey: MyNestedModel
}

struct MyNestedModel: Encodable {
    let key0: String
    let key1: String
    let key2: String
}
```

And after:

```
do {
    let requestBody = MyRequestBodyModel(...)
    request.httpBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(requestBody)
} catch {
    // Handle error here
}
```

I think this way is clearer and easier to maintain.